# Why can't a bound vector determine a free vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, vectors

According to the 3rd paragraph of the introduction of this [article](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Efaris/vector5.pdf),

> Each bound vector $P, \textbf{u}$ determines a sliding vector
> $P ∧\textbf{u}$... Each sliding vector $P ∧$ **u** determines a free
> vector **u**. The maps are summarized by
>
> $$(P, \textbf{u}) \mapsto P ∧ \textbf{u} \mapsto \textbf{u}$$

My question is, why can't a bound vector determine a free vector?

If a bound vector determines a sliding vector, and a sliding vector determines a free vector, then isn't the bound vector already indirectly determining a free vector? So, why can't a bound vector directly determine a free vector?

Comment: Of course it can! What makes you think it can't? The map is obviously $(P,\mathbf{u}) \mapsto \mathbf{u}$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh haha. Thanks for your comment. I'm a complete amateur.